# Optimizing MySQL SELECT from huge table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm doing regular

```
SELECT * FROM sensor_data_1sec LIMIT 491160, 30
```

from this table: http://test.dev.brown.sk/sensor_data_1sec.zip

It tooks about 0.06s. I think it is too much. MySQL server is on my PC with Intel Core i7, 8 GB RAM, Windows 7.

Take a look on phpMyAdmin: 
[image]

Of course it took much little time when it is cached. But is it possible to make it faster uncached?

Comment: The query in your question isn't the same as in the screenshot, you have an extra `WHERE` that doesn't belong.

Comment: What is there in your query to optimize? It has no join conditions, no WHERE test.

Comment: phpMyAdmin says it took 0.0269s, not 0.06s. You seem to have missed a digit. So it's twice as fast as you thought.

Comment: it was another select

Comment: Why did you paste an image if it's not relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Six hundredths (or two hundredths) of a second is *fine.* The basic rule is that a user shouldn't be kept waiting for too long and I generally put that at half a second.

Is there something you may have acheived in that 0.06s that you're bothered about, had you known it was going to be that slow? :-)

As an aside, it's unwise to assume a particular order in a result set from a query with no ordering clause. It's also usually preferred to explicitly select columns rather than using `*`.

Comment: You were right before you edited, phpMyAdmin says 2 hundredths, not 6 hundredths.

Comment: @Barmar, I assumed the php admin was for comparison, OP explicitly states 0.06. However, it doesn't matter whether it's 0.02 or 0.06, it's still blindingly fast. I'll edit to make that clear, thanks.

Comment: I agree with that, +1.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because off the deep scan. 
An large offset in the LIMIT is bad very bad, if you run an EXPLAIN you will see it needs a temporary table to handle this. And this temporary is proberly disk based because it needs the memory off 491190 records. So you are killing the MySQL performance now.